# Insert multiple values in one column mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of checkboxes and values, if a user selects a checkbox they select the value of the id in an array called checkedHW for simplicity sake this is what code looks like:

```
$ids = implode(',',arrayofids);

$sql = "insert into table(id, type) values($ids,type);
$db->query($sql);
```

echo query for testing:

```
"insert into table('id1,id2','type')
```

I figured that if I loop through this query I could hypothetically do this:

```
"insert into table('id1','type');"

"insert into table('id2','type');"
```

but I'm not exactly quite sure how to do, any help would be wonderful :)

I actually solved it using:

```
for($i=0;$i<count(arrayofids); $i++){
$sql = "insert into table(id,type) values(array[$i], 'type'";
$db->query($sql);}
```

I hope that helps someone and thank you guys for the help!

Comment: i think `id` dataType is int.

Comment: I just added an int cast and it only inserts a row for the first value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
$base = 'INSERT INTO table (id, type) VALUES (';
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$values = implode(", 'type'), (", $array);
$query = $base . $values . ", 'type')";

$db->query($query);
```

This is what would be getting submitted:

```
INSERT INTO table (id, type) VALUES (1, 'type'), (2, 'type'), (3, 'type'), (4, 'type')
```

Comment: i was able to solve it without using implode, but thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Both query are completely different

`insert into table('id1,id2','type')` will insert single row

> id1,id2 | type

whereas

```
insert into table('id1','type');"

insert into table('id2','type');"
```

will insert two rows

> id1 | type
>   id2 | type

so if your **id** column is `int` type then you cant run first query

Answer (score 0):

If you have a series of checkboxes, and wanting to insert the values into your table, you could loop through them like this:

```
<?php

$values = array();

foreach ($_POST['field_name'] as $i => $value) {
    $values[] = sprintf('(%d)', $value);
}

$values = implode(',', $values);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`column_name`) VALUES $values";
```

This will give you a SQL query similar to:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`column_name`) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4)
```

Hope this help.